# Nullpointer Exception when trying to access Injected Bean

Tags: java, maven, code-injection

I have a maven multi module project. When trying to Access a injected bean i get a Nullpointer Exception.

this is the main Function that startsthe application

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Startpoint");
        DecisionMaker decisionMaker = new DecisionMaker();
        decisionMaker.run();
    }
}
```

this is what i do in the DecisionMaker

```
public class DecisionMaker {

@Inject
GameListener gm;

@Inject
BasicProductionManager basicProductionManager;

public DecisionMaker() {
    System.out.println("this is the decisionmaker");
    System.out.println(gm.toString());
}
```

so this is not an bean but a normal pojo

the gamelistener is a Applicationscoped bean which i want to inject.

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped

public class GameListener extends DefaultBWListener {

@Inject
Event<OnFrameEvent> onFrameEvent;

public Mirror mirror = new Mirror();

public Game game;

public Player self;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    System.out.println("init listener");
}
```

the nullpointer gets thrown in the constructor of the DecisionMaker. The @PostConscrutct init method is not called

I looked into similar question but all i found is that i needthe PostConstruct method which i already have.

Comment: Is there any spring application context? Does not look like it - how do you expect `gm` to get a value? Who / what is supposed to set it?

Comment: What dependency injection framework are you using?

Comment: <dependency>
     <groupId>javax</groupId>
     <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
     <version>7.0</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
</dependency>

Comment: `new` does not respect annotations.  You need to ask the framework properly for an instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't instantiate `DecisionMaker` yourself. the whole point of CDI is to give it control of creating and managing beans.

check out this [article](https://randling.wordpress.com/2011/08/15/cdi-in-java-se/) to see how to use CDI in JAVA SE.

Comment: thanks alot i will try this, i thought i have to create one Object first from my static main function to get the project rolling.

Comment: @MarcusLanvers think of CDI like spring IOC, you don't create  or manage any instances yourself, you give that responsibility to spring.

Comment: ok i think i get this, but i still have the problem that my startpoint is the static main function and after i created my bean like this : Weld weld = new Weld();
  WeldContainer container = weld.initialize();
  DecisionMaker application = container.instance().select(DecisionMaker.class).get();
  DecisionMaker.run(); 
  weld.shutdown(); : i have the prolbem that it says DecisionMaker.run(); must be static wich i dont want it to be

Comment: @MarcusLanvers bcoz you saying `DecisionMaker.run();` instead of `application.run()`, please rename the instance variable for `DecisionMaker`

Comment: oh im so stupid, my apollogys for not looking first TT. Thanks alot it should work now

Comment: @MarcusLanvers if it helped,please accept the answer

Comment: so i am able to instanciate my decisionMaker bean, but i still get the same nullpointer when using my listerner bean. Also i get this error message "703 [main] INFO org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap - WELD-000101 Transactional services not available. Injection of @Inject UserTransaction not available. Transactional observers will be invoked synchronously." i have my weld dependencys set and created the beans.xml files. Do i need to do something more to for weld to work?